# Observing self in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing

In Cocoa, `addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` retains "neither the receiver, nor anObserver". Therefore I assume observing self is allowed; that is, it's perfectly valid to do something like

`[self addObserver:self forKeyPath...]`

As long as you remember to unregister `self` as an observer as the first thing in dealloc.

Is this assumption correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is not really any reason you can't observe self.  But like you said, like any KVO observation, make sure to remove yourself as an observer before being dealloced.

For the record, one alternate way of doing this if you're just talking about a simple key is to write a custom setter and execute whatever code you need in the setter.  This style makes it a little more obvious what the full effects of calling the setter are. The KVO way is a bit more flexible though, and works with key paths that contain multiple components.

Answer (score 1):

I do what Brian Webster said. Here's an example:

```
//.h
...
@property(readwrite, retain, setter=setMyPropertySynth:) id myProperty;
-(void)setMyProperty:(id)newValue;
....


//.m
...
@synthesize myProperty;

-(void)setMyProperty:(id)newValue
{
    //add code here

    [self setMyPropertySynth:newValue];

    //add more code here
}
...
```

Comment: This is not a good idea. It is generally expected that `obj.foo = bar;` should be equivalent to `[obj setFoo:bar];` and straying from this pattern will confuse others that are reading/maintaining your code

Comment: @rpetrich I agree that this is not a good idea (I wrote that answer over 18 months ago), but for a different reason. I would no longer use `@synthesize`; I would now write the whole getter and setter. The extra burden of a few extra lines outweighs the cost of mentally following the extra method calls (I'd still use `@property`). I disagree that side effects in setters (or getters) are inherently bad. They should be avoided where possible. For example, setting `hypotheticalQueryObject.maxResults = 4;` could legitimately trigger another search.

Comment: @rpetrich That actually is guaranteed. `obj.foo = bar;` always uses whatever implementation of `setFoo:` is provided (even if you've overridden a synthesized one).

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling: Actually, it's not. In this case, `obj.myProperty = foo;` is equivalent to `[obj setMyPropertySynth:foo]` instead of `[obj setMyProperty:foo]`. Do reread Benedict's answer.

Answer (score -1):

Don't remove an observer in `-dealloc`. Why? Because when you turn on the garbage collector things will stop working; `-dealloc` never gets called. You should just use the `-dealloc` and `-finalize` methods for *memory-related* cleanup code.

Comment: Just set it up as part of the object's lifecycle. If the thing that creates it tells it what to observe, and when to stop observing it, you're _injecting dependencies_ which makes your object easier to re-use and to test.

Comment: ...but much easier to use incorrectly, and undermines Cocoa memory management. If every creator must also know that the created object must observer such-and-such (particularly if that's itself), we've moved private information into the caller, which is bad. Worse, if I need a "destroy you now" method that undoes this observation, then the whole point of GC went out the window. The best solution we have is to duplicate the non-memory management pieces into dealloc and finalize (possibly hoisting to a shared routine). This include NSNotificationCenter removeObserver as well.

Comment: I think in ARC you still use dealloc, however the only difference is you don't call [super dealloc] in there.